# How to find Probabilities Using Bayes Rule in Python's Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1. I'm trying to find the probability P(A1,A3|A2) using Bayes' rule with the aim of using
   P(A1,A3|A2)=P(A2|A1,A3)*P(A1,A3)/P(A2).
2. How would I compute P(A1 union A2) = P(A1) + P(A2) - P(A2|A1)P(A1)?

I'm working with this data set [DataCSV](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/blob/master/comma-survey/comma-survey.csv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
data['temp']=data[A1]+data[A3]
data.groupby(A2)['temp'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts('normalize'))
```

output:

[image]